Functors such that $F \circ G=Id$
I'm very sorry for my silly question. Suppose that $F: \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ and $G: \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{C}$ are two functors satisfying the equality $F \circ G=Id_\mathcal{D}$. What can I say about the functors $F$ and $G$? And if something may be said (for instance $F$ or $G$ satisfies some property, does such a statement admit a converse?

Is section and retraction what you’re looking for?

Do you mean in the large category of categories and functors? If yes, are these functors full, faithful or not? Because a section is a monic in a category. What about monics of the large category of categories and functors?

$F$ and $G$ form a section-retraction pair in the category of strict categories. See here and here.

This turns out to not be a very "categorically natural" condition in practice, because it doesn't make any use of natural transformations. The "categorically natural" version of this condition, which frequently arises in practice, is the following: if $F : C \to D, G : D \to C$ are an adjoint pair of functors, then they are equipped with two natural transformations called the counit and the unit
$$\varepsilon : F \circ G \to \text{id}_D, \eta : G \circ F \to \text{id}_D$$
and now we can ask for the counit to be invertible (so it exhibits a natural isomorphism between $F \circ G$ and $\text{id}_D$). This happens iff the right adjoint $G$ is fully faithful, so it exhibits $D$ as a full subcategory of $C$, and then the left adjoint $F$ is called a reflector and $D$ is called a reflective subcategory. So the idea here is that the left adjoint "reflects" an object of the larger category $C$ down into the smaller category $D$. The invertibility of the counit then just says that if you reflect an object that is already in $D$ you just get that object again.
Here are some quick examples to convey the flavor of this condition.

If $C = \text{Grp}$ is the category of groups and $D = \text{Ab}$ is the full subcategory of abelian groups, then the reflector exists and is the abelianization $G \mapsto G/[G, G]$. If a group is abelian it is its own abelianization.
If $C = \text{Ab}$ is the category of abelian groups and $D$ is the full subcategory of torsion-free abelian groups, then the reflector exists and is the torsion-free quotient $A \mapsto A/A_{\text{tors}}$. If a group is torsion-free it is its own torsion-free quotient.
If $C = \text{Dom}$ is the category of integral domains and injective homomrphisms and $D$ is the subcategory of fields, then the reflector exists and is the field of fractions $A \mapsto \text{Frac}(A)$. If a domain is a field it is its own field of fractions.
If $C = \text{Top}$ is the category of topological spaces and $D$ is the full subcategory of Hausdorff topological spaces, then the reflector exists and is the Hausdorffization. If a space is Hausdorff it is its own Hausdorffization.
If $C = \text{Met}_{\le 1}$ is the category of metric spaces and short maps (non-distance-increasing) and $D$ is the subcategory of complete metric spaces, then the reflector exists and is the Cauchy completion. If a metric space is complete it is its own Cauchy completion.


Sometimes $F\circ G$ really does equal the identity. If $F$ is left adjoint to $G$ then sometimes $F$ is called a lali (left adjoint left inverse) functor and $G,$ a rari (sim). Of course you could equally well have $F$ as the right adjoint so it becomes a rali and $G,$ a lari.
